# TextBox search populating two DataGridViews

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

In my current situation the `TextChanged` event of `TextBox1` is used to bind search results to `dgv1`.

The `SelectionChanged` event of `dgv1` is in turn used to fill `dgv2`, i.e. `dgv2` contains information of current selection/row of `dgv1`.

Everything works perfect except for two scenarios that I know of:

- No results from `TextBox1` search: `dgv1` correctly displays nothing, but `dgv2` displays information from previously existing `dgv1` selection.
- If first row index is currently selected from `dgv1` and a new search is performed and the results are updated but the row index remains the same (still the first): `dgv2` isn't updated.

Codes:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Using conn As New SqlConnection, comm As New SqlCommand 'etc...
        Try
            conn.Open()
            comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM..."

            'Set dgv1 DataSource...
        Catch ex As Exception
            DisplayExceptionMessageBox(ex)
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub dgv1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgv1.SelectionChanged
    dgv2.DataSource = Nothing
    If dgv1.CurrentRow Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'SELECT * FROM... WHERE id = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
        'Bind to dgv2
    End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Your help is much appreciated.
Best Regards.

Comment: you can move the `dgv2.DataSource = Nothing` line to the beginning of TextBox1_TextChanged

Comment: @Slai `dgv2`Still not updating correctly when no `dgv1` results... :(

Comment: Regardless of your issue, your implementation leaves a bit to be desired.  Let's say that the user wants type four letters into that `TextBox`. Your code is going to force them to execute four queries when they only need one and it will also force them to wait between queries before the `TextBox` will show the next letter.  The proper way to implement something like this would be to start or restart a `Timer` in the `TextChanged` event handler and then only search when that `Ticks`. That way, you won't do any irrelevant searching between typed letters unless the user types too slowly.

Comment: Also, what's the point of using `If...Else` in that second event handler?  Why not simply get rid of the first block and invert the condition?  There's NEVER any point using an `Exit Sub` statement when the next step will be the `End Sub` line anyway.